# Is it possible to keep setgid bit when unzipping files as non-root user?

Tags: permissions, root, zip, unzip, acl

I have a folder with the following permissions:

```
drwxrws--x+ 13 myuser  www-data      4096 Mar 20 09:57 project-folder
```

In this folder I have an archive `archive.zip` with the following permissions:

```
-rw-rw----+    1 myuser www-data  10260 Mar 20 09:56 archive.zip
```

When I unzipped archive by calling `unzip archive.zip` I got the following file listing:

```
drwxrwx--x+    3 myuser www-data   4096 May  5  2017 folder-from-archive
```

As we can see, the owner group is `www-data` as same for parent folder `project-folder`, but the `folder-from-archive` does not have the **setgid** bit (the `s` in the permissions string) and the content of this folder is not owned by group `www-data`:

```
-rw-rw----+ 1 myuser myuser 1083 May  5  2017 LICENSE
-rw-rw----+ 1 myuser myuser 2197 May  5  2017 README.md
-rw-rw----+ 1 myuser myuser  720 May  5  2017 autoload.php
-rw-rw----+ 1 myuser myuser  786 May  5  2017 composer.json
drwxrwx--x+ 3 myuser myuser 4096 May  5  2017 source
```

But when I tried unzipping this archive as root user the permissions and group owner (as well as the files in the folder) were correct:

```
drwxr-s--x+    3 root www-data   4096 May  5  2017 folder-from-archive
```

Files in folder `folder-from-archive`:

```
-rw-r-----+ 1 root www-data 1083 May  5  2017 LICENSE
-rw-r-----+ 1 root www-data 2197 May  5  2017 README.md
-rw-r-----+ 1 root www-data  720 May  5  2017 autoload.php
-rw-r-----+ 1 root www-data  786 May  5  2017 composer.json
drwxr-s--x+ 3 root www-data 4096 May  5  2017 source
```

As we can see after unzipping by root user the folder inherited the setgid bit and set correct group `www-data` for itself and all containing files.

How to get the same behavior for the user `myuser`?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313656/preserving-permissions-while-zipping/313685) about preserving permissions.

Answer (score 0):

That behavior was default but later it began to be considered as security issue (CVE-2005-0602).

`unzip --help` shows argument that should help: `-K  keep setuid/setgid/tacky permissions`.
Therefore command should be `unzip -K archive.zip`.

Comment: I know about this option, but it does not work. I've already tried this by myuser `unzip -K archive.zip`, this is output `ls -l` command `drwxrwx--x+    3 myuser www-data   4096 May  5  2017 project-folder. So, there is no setgid permissions. But why it's working for root without this option?

Comment: I think `-K` is default for root user.
Anyway it works for me: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WZMMJcxMgq/

Comment: Your example is incorrect. You should have different user owner and group owner, also u have to have setgid bit on the root folder (`chmod g+s folder`) and inherit it after unzip (the goal is inherit owner group of root folder, owner group is different for the owner user, and unzipped dir also should have setgid bit.